# This came off in my car. Car is Honda Accord sport 2014

Tags: honda, part-identification

[image]

Was driving my car just fine, then was on a road going up hill and I heard like a thumping noise. Parked and saw this thing unconnected. What is the name of this, what does it do, how much to fix, or can I do it myself? I just had my front wheel bearing replaced a couple days ago and my uncle (guy who replaced the wheel bearing) saw that it was unconnected and either knew it didn’t matter and didn’t connect it. Or connected it and it came off again.

Comment: A better picture will help as it is difficult to work out what it is... But something not connected needs to be fixed...

Comment: Where is this on the car? Front? Back? Underneath?

Comment: And welcome to the site, by the way!  If you could retake that picture in better lighting, and then explain where on the car it came off of, that would help us know what it is, and better advise you.

Comment: Look at the other side and see how the companion part on the opposable side is connected for reference where it should connect. You might just be a washer and a nut away from being able to reconnect it. If you need to buy those, remove them from the good side and take them with you to the store--they can match them there with some templates most all parts stores have.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to be honest and say now that this might be the worst picture I've seen taken in the last 5 years, but that looks like one of your front swaybar end-links (also referred to as the anti-roll bar end-link or stabilizer link).

The end-link connects your sway bar to your suspension arm or wheel knuckle. The sway bar somewhat connects the suspension on the left side of your car to the right side, which can reduce body roll while turning, or "stabilize" the car. If you've worked on your car before, you should be able to replace the end-link, although they can be a bit fussy to disconnect/reconnect. If your uncle can replace your wheel bearing, then he can replace the end-link.

The reason why it didn't really "matter" to your uncle is because your car doesn't need the swaybar to drive. It can improve handling in general, but it isn't an absolutely necessary component. However, as others have commented, you should get it fixed soon because it's not good to leave parts broken on your car, and the handling balance may be thrown off - it'll be biased towards oversteer now.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I disagree that it doesn't "matter".  We have no way of judging how the OP drives, and an Accord Sport is likely to have a rear anti-roll bar as well.  The disconnected front now completely changes the roll couple, and could result in a tail-happy oversteer and loss of control if cornered aggressively.

Comment: Updated answer slightly to reflect this. Also on a completely unrelated note, at long last, I have earned my expanded user card with this answer! Finally people will be able to see that the backdrop in my avatar isn't just a plain white background!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, but congratulations!